# Mailchimp API upload to File Manager Files

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have a form that updates the content of the campaign, 1 image and 1 text area. The content section for text works fine, as for the image I am thinking to upload the image to MailChimp then use the response URL of the image they send back to replace the section content for the image.

Uploading a file using Mailchimp API but have gotten this error and I can't seem to find anyone with the same problem.

I have tried uploading from Mailchimp website and it works. The image size is only 4kb.

```
Status: 400 | {"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"detail":"Maximum gallery size of 1gb has been reached. Please delete some files and retry your upload.","instance":"298af7d6-f749-41e1-a090-8b1be5bcd74b"}
```

Have chatted with Mailchimp technical team and he said "Ok so the 1GB error is a limitation that extends from an error message for general. The error message just hasn't been updated to reflect that. The workaround is to just upload in the app directly."

[See screenshot of my request call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HErbq.png)

Could someone please let me know if I am doing it correctly?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.